# How to jest test a DetailPanel-Property of an React Material Table

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, material-ui, material-table

In the picture above I have a MaterialTable with some informations and the posibility to perform (1) actions and (2) expand a detail panel with some more informations. The following code example is perfectly working for me in the application.

```
<MaterialTable
            title={title}
            tableRef={tableRef}
            columns={[
                { title: "ID", field: "id", type: "string", hidden: true },
                { title: "Resource Type", field: "type", type: "string", filtering: false },
                {
                    title: "Amount",
                    field: "amount",
                    type: "numeric",
                    filtering: false
                },
                { title: "Status", field: "status", type: "string", filtering: false }
            ]}
            data={data}
            onRowClick={() => handleClick()}
            options={{ filtering, paging, idSynonym: "id" }}
            detailPanel={[
                {
                    tooltip: "Availability",
                    render: (rowData) => {
                        console.log("DETAIL-PANEL");
                        return <DetailPanel rowData={rowData.rowData} />;
                    }
                }
            ]}
            actions={[
                {
                    icon: () => <EditIcon />,
                    tooltip: "Edit",
                    onClick: () => handleClick()
                },
                {
                    icon: () => <CopyIcon />,
                    tooltip: "Duplicate",
                    onClick: () => handleClick()
                },
                {
                    icon: () => <DeleteIcon />,
                    tooltip: "Delete",
                    onClick: () => handleClick()
                }
            ]}
        />
```

So the next step would be testing. And here I already wrote tests for the (1) actions and now wanted to do the same for the (2) detail panel.

```
test(`renders the "Availability" detail panel`, () => {
    render(<DetailPanel />, {
        wrapper
    });

    const element = screen.getByRole("row", {
        name: /dish 25 committed/i
    });

    userEvent.click(
        within(element).getByRole("button", {
            name: /detail panel visibility toggle/i
        })
    );
});
```

Now I get my `console.log("DETAIL-PANEL")` output from the detailPanel but I dont get my log-statement from within the DetailPanle-Component. It doesnt open the detailPanel...

Clicking the action-icons inside my tests (opens a "under construction"-dialog) is working perfectly and "shows" me my dialog.

Am I missing something, so that my component inside the detailPanel gets visible for testing?

Answer (score 0):

```
test(`renders the "Availability" detail panel`, async () => {
    render(<AccreditedResourcesOverviewTable />, {
        wrapper
    });

    const element = screen.getByRole("row", {
        name: /dish 25 committed/i
    });

    userEvent.click(
        within(element).getByRole("button", {
            name: /detail panel visibility toggle/i
        })
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
        const detailPanel = screen.getByText(/availability/i);
        expect(detailPanel).toBeVisible();
    });
});
```

Making the test asynchronous and then `waitFor` the "animation" of expanding the detail-panel to test the content helped and fixed my issue